# Is it possible to to only stub a call with specific parameters with minitest?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have multiple calls to `::Foo.bar`. I would like to stub only the call that includes a very specific parameter.

Is it possible to do : `::Foo.stubs(:bar).with(1).returns(something)` and still allow `::Foo.bar(2)` to call the actual method?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `instance_of` in the parameter, if the value will be an instance of the same class.

```
::Foo.stubs(:bar).with(instance_of(Integer)).returns(something)
```

Please refer the [source code](https://github.com/freerange/mocha/blob/d8019eed369bff98b76ab05d7abe6fdc1ad71f86/lib/mocha/expectation.rb#L213) of `with`, a block can also be passed to match your requirements.